# Compare 2 Integer numbers, strange behavior

Tags: java

I wrote the simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i1 = 127;
    Integer i2 = 127;
    boolean flag1 = i1 == i2;
    System.out.println(flag1);

    Integer i3 = 128;
    Integer i4 = 128;
    boolean flag2 = i3 == i4;
    System.out.println(flag2);
}
```

But, strangely, the result is as below:

```
true
false
```

Can you guys please explain why the difference occurs?

Comment: Change Integer -> int, so the results be the same.

Comment: Alternatively use `i3.equals(i4)` in place of `i3 == i4`.

Comment: For more details http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/surprising-results-of-autoboxing.html

Comment: Simple, you don't compare Objects with ==

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Integer`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) are *objects*, the `==` operator *might* "work" (in the sense of what you expect it to do - to compare *values*) only for numbers between [-128,127]. Look at the [JLS - **5.1.7. Boxing Conversion**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is `true`, `false`, a `byte`, or a `char` in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an `int` or `short` number between **-128** and **127**
>   (inclusive), then let `r1` and `r2` be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `r1 == r2`.

The values you're comparing are not in the range, the result is evaluated to `false`. You should use [`Integer#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead, or simply use the lovely primitive `int`.

Comment: He could also use int instead to make it work.